# Is it useful to train a CycleGAN in a supervised setting?

Tags: deep-learning, applications, generative-adversarial-networks

I am very interested in the application of CycleGANs. I understand the concept of unpaired data and it makes sense to me.

But now a question comes to my mind: what if I have enough paired image data, is then a CycleGAN an over-engineering, if I use it in a "supervised" setting (input matches with the label - but still a CycleGAN)? For what kind of application could it be useful? Would it be more useful to process it using a "normal" supervised setting?

So, basically, my question is whether it is useful to train a CycleGAN in a supervised setting?

Comment: Right now im trying cyclegan dcgan implementation on this (paired pictures from danbooru dressed to nude. cycle_gan model). I ll report text result in comparison to pix2pix here asap. But maybe 5-7 days will require.